# QSet intersection without losing elements

Tags: c++, qt, set

How to take an intersection between 2 QSets where the first does not lose elements, but just the resulting intersection is returned?

The reason is that I am trying to perform many intersections with some sets, but had to find out the hard way that the elements were lost in the process.

```
QSet<int> a, b;
a.insert(1);
a.insert(2);         // { 1, 2 }
b.insert(1);         // { 1 }
a.intersection(b);   // { 1 }  
a                    // { 1 }
```

Comment: just make a copy! Overhead is almost none since Qt uses "copy on write" pattern for all containers. This will do the trick: `c = QSet<int>(a).intersection(b);`. This is how the operator `&` is defined for `QSet` see [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/4f2c96eaa8bfa4d8a6dfb92096e4e4030d0cdea7:src/corelib/tools/qset.h#L223).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`intersect` modifies the set you apply it to. If you don't want to do that, don't use `intersect`.

The overloaded `operator&` returns a new `QSet` that's the intersection of two `QSet`s. There's also an assignment operator `operator&=`.

[`QSet`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qset.html) is hash-based. If you're working with sets of small integers and you're concerned with efficiency, [`QBitArray`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qbitarray.html) might work better.

Comment: Beat me to it. `QSet<int> c = a & b;`

Comment: In fact they are large sets with large integers. I am not sure on the use of the operators...

Comment: @Dualinity: How large? A `QBitArray` should have size proportional to the maximum value; a `QSet` should have size proportional to the number of members of the set (so the set `{ 999999999999 }` would make for a large `QBitArray` but a small `QSet`). A `QBitArray` is likely to be smaller and faster for relatively dense sets of integers. What are you not sure about with respect to the operators?

Comment: I found out that indeed the operator&() does what I was looking for! I have indices between 1 and 6000000 as integers. What would be the advice? I have to do 13000x6000 intersections...

Comment: @Dualinity: It still depends. How dense are the sets (i.e., how many members does each set contain)? How many set objects exist at once? A `QBitArray` will probably store 1 bit per element in the full range plus some overhead, or about 0.75 MB per set in your case. A `QSet` will probably store somewhere around 8 bytes (that's a wild guess) per actual member of the set. Consider implementing it both ways and measuring both memory usage and run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to copy the original set and then intersect it, you could create a function that creates a new set from the intersection:

```
template<class T>
QSet<T> intersectSets(const QSet<T>& a, const QSet<T>& b) {
   QSet<T> result;
   foreach(const T& value, a)
      if (b.contains(value))
         result.insert(value);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Any idea on the speed? Would it beat `QVector` using `contains`?

Comment: QSet uses a hash table internally, so I guess it will be much faster than QVector as the number of elements grows

Comment: @Dualinity How many elements contains each of the sets you're intersecting?

Comment: Varying from 0 to 100000+